# Почему не работает плагин CSS Navigation в VSCode?

Tags: visual-studio-code

Выделяю нужный элемент, зажимаю <kbd>ctrl</kbd> - не работает.
Выделяю нужный элемент, <kbd>f12</kbd> - не работает

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Добавьте больше информации, какая структура проекта, приведите короткий пример кода с которым вы работаете. Для этого в можете нажать [edit] под самим вопросом